# Restricting user input length and what it can be divisible by

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a validation method in python so that the input of the message from the user must be more than 8 characters and be able to be divisible by 4 (characters that has a length oF 8,12,16,20 etc..)

below is the source code i have done

```
while True:
    messagetoencode = input().upper()
    if len(messagetoencode) < 8 :
        if len(messagetoencode) % 4 ==0
            break
        print("Message must be more than 8 characters & divisible by 4")
```

if I type in a string value of 4 characters it still continues my program, but the validation does work when the  string length is less than 8 (except for the value 4 itself)

Comment: I would suggest an `and` or `&&`. Also ;)

Comment: ill try that thank you, i've change it again above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"input of the message from the user must be more than 8 characters and be able to be divisible by 4"*

To accomplish this, you could use:

```
while True:
    messagetoencode = input().upper()
    if len(messagetoencode) > 8 and len(messagetoencode) % 4 == 0:
        break
    else:
        print("Message must be more than 8 characters & divisible by 4")
```

You want to compare if the length of the input is `>` than `8`, not `<`. I'm not sure if you want to allow length `8` too (you will have to change `>` to `>=`)

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer, If it was useful and solved your problem : [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)